# create constance django from model list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-settings

I need to implement functionality when only one user of users Model can has 'editor-role' I will use this constant in my drf api. So I need to create some django constant with one user id, and dropdown menu of all users in my django admin panel. How can I do it? Any another ideas how to implement this functionality?
I choose django-constant, but faced with the problem that list of model data couldn't init in settings py:

```
CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'

CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS = {
    'users_select': ['django.forms.fields.ChoiceField', {
        'widget': 'django.forms.Select',
        'choices': (
            (None, "-----"),
            User.objects.all().split(","))
        )
    }],
}

CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'DEFAULT_USER': ('', 'default user', 'users_select'),
}
```

UPD I decide use json file for the list, but still not sure its the best result. Maybe I will find the better desigion

```
def users_list():
    f = open('apps/users/data.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    result = ((user['id'], user['full_name']) for user in data)
    f.close()
    return tuple(result)

CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS = {
    'user_select': ['django.forms.fields.ChoiceField', {
        'widget': 'django.forms.Select',
        'choices': (
            (None, "-----"),
        ) + users_list()
    }],
}
```